# WebScraping with LXML.HTML and Xpath

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I try to extract information from a website but unfortunately I only get limited extent. I have problems with the right Xpath to receive more than just the first element of the whole table. To display the Xpath I use Chrome DevTools. How can I make the Xpath more general to get the desired result? Or does anyone have an idea how I can do this a little more cleverly? My goal is to get a json file later.

```python
import requests
import lxml.html

html = requests.get('http://volcano.oregonstate.edu/volcano_table')
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)

volcanoes = doc.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a/text()')
country = doc.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()')
latitude = doc.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/text()')
longitude = doc.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/text()')
elevation = doc.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/text()')

output = []
for info in zip(volcanoes, country, latitude, longitude, elevation):
    resp = {}
    resp['volcanoes'] = info[0]
    resp['country'] = info[1]
    resp['latitude'] = info[2]
    resp['longitude'] = info[3]
    resp['elevation'] = info[4]
    output.append(resp)

print(output)
```

This is what the code is able to receive for the moment:

```python
[{'volcanoes': 'Abu', 'country': '\n            Japan          ', 'latitude': '\n            34.50          ', 'longitude': '\n            131.60          ', 'elevation': '\n            641          '}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your defined `xpaths` are error prone. I've tried to improve them. Now, the following should get you the required content.

```
import json
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

res = requests.get('http://volcano.oregonstate.edu/volcano_table')
root = fromstring(res.text)
data = []
for item in root.xpath("//*[starts-with(@class,'views-table')]//tbody//tr"):
    d = {}
    d['volcan'] = item.xpath('.//td/a/text()')[0].strip()
    d['country'] = item.xpath('.//td/text()')[2].strip()
    d['lat'] = item.xpath('.//td/text()')[4].strip()
    d['longitude'] = item.xpath('.//td/text()')[5].strip()
    d['elevation'] = item.xpath('.//td/text()')[6].strip()
    data.append(d)

print(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
```

Output you may have like:

```
[
    {
        "volcan": "Abu",
        "country": "Japan",
        "lat": "34.50",
        "longitude": "131.60",
        "elevation": "641"
    },
    {
        "volcan": "Acamarachi",
        "country": "Chile",
        "lat": "-23.30",
        "longitude": "-67.62",
        "elevation": "6046"
    },
```